# Using data-target with variable ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Having issues with assigning a variable ID to a data-target to trigger a bootstrap modal.

Is there a reason why this shouldn't behave as expected?

Simplified code which works:

```
    <div class="column">
    <!-- The trigger: -->
    <a class="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalTrigger">Here</a> 
    
    <!-- Which triggers: -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Then when I swap the ID to use a variable, the modal trigger no longer works:

```
    <script id="test" type="text/html">

    <div class="column">
    <!-- The trigger: -->
    <a class="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= ID %>">Here</a>    
    <!-- Which triggers: -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="<%= ID %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
    </div>

    </script>
```

Because the ID needs to be unique to trigger the appropriate modal window, I need to be able to assign a unique value. I am using "ID" which is unique to each json data record, however the event will not trigger.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Make sure the `data-target` and `id` values are actually correct. Also make sure each `id` is unique in the document. What sort of values are the `ID`s?

Comment: Bootstrap 4, the IDs are also numbered values

Comment: I'd try prefixing them with a string, eg `#modal-<%= ID %>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="example" runat="server" />
```

in your aspx page
and then use Value of that hiddenfield in your data-target and for id like this:

```
<a class="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%=example.Value %>">Here</a>    

<div class="modal fade" id="<%=example.Value %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
```

I don't know about ID in your code and where did that comes from. but from wherever your ID comes from you should set into hiddenfield value and then read the value of that hiddenfield in your tag.
I hope I was able to help you guy.